# How to catch isHexDigit Exception in WeldListener?

Tags: java, glassfish, illegalstateexception

From somewhere I got some stupid and invalid URL Request to a Webservice, like

```
http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/webresources/testme?stupidparameter=dyndcvgz/&%$\xa7edns
```

My sample Application looks like following, build with Netbeans on glassfish 4.0 and jdk1.7u40

```
package WebApplication1;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

@Stateless
@Path("/testme")
public class NewSessionBean {
    /**
     * http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/webresources/testme?stupidparameter=dyndcvgz/&%$\xa7edns
     *
     * @param stupidparameter
     * @return
     */
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getXml(
            @QueryParam("stupidparameter") String stupidparameter) {
        System.out.println("stupidparameter = " + stupidparameter);

        return "got " + stupidparameter;
    }
}
```

and with the given test url I always got IllegalStateException: isHexDigit from org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener. How can I avoid or handle this exception?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a problem with Glassfish, the way it's processing parameters with special characters.

https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1538

Until the issue is resolved in a future release, you could try to encode the parameter as base64 and decode it back when the paramter is received inside `getXml()`. This would avoid having related special characters from passing through logic inside glassfish where the exception is thrown.